# I'm getting an error while uploading my code to esp8266 via an arduino (FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error)))

Tags: esp8266, wifi, arduino-uno-wifi, esp

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Executable segment sizes:

IROM   : 228624          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 

IRAM   : 26756   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 

DATA   : 1248  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

RODATA : 688   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

BSS    : 24880 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

Sketch uses 257316 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 958448 bytes.

Global variables use 26816 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55104 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

esptool.py v2.8

Serial port COM3

Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Reghunaath A A\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>

    esptool.main(cmdline)

  File "C:/Users/Reghunaath A A/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main

    esp.connect(args.before)

  File "C:/Users/Reghunaath A A/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect

    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header



_



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I'm getting the above stated error message while I'm trying to upload a code to esp8266 via an arduino(I've removed the ATMEGA32 from my arduino). Sometimes it gets uploaded without a problem(very rarely) but mostly the upload fails.
I connected rx of arduino to rx of esp and same for tx too. 3.3v of arduino to enable and vcc of esp. graund of arduino to ground of esp and gpio0.

The code that I'm trying to upload:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forevervoid lop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
  // but actually the LED is on; this is because
  // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

My settings:
[image]

EDIT: Also, I want to add one more thing when the message box says "Connecting........_____....._" during that time if i reset the esp the code starts uploading

Comment: @jsotola bruh half of my question is missing. Let me update it.

Comment: @jsotola please check it out now.

Comment: do you put the esp8266 in flashing mode?

Comment: @Juraj yes I connected the esp0 to groung

Comment: io 0 to gnd, then reset?

Comment: @Juraj I left reset unconnected

Comment: @Juraj yes after connecting io 0 to ground i do a reset by unplugging and plugging back the groud of the esp8266

Comment: add to question the module you have, how did you wire it and how do you put it in flashing mode

Comment: @Juraj I aded the wiring info to the question and I want to share with you one more thing that I observed recently, when the message box says "Connecting........_____....._" during that time if i reset the esp the code starts uploading

Comment: to put the esp8266 in flashing mode, io 0 must be pulled-down at boot (power up or reset) simply to tell the bootloader to start in flashing mode. the bootloader checks if the pin is HIGH or LOW. no magic. for normal run io 0 must be pulled up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set esp 8266 to flash mode.
Please connect en PIN to Gnd pin.
Then flash again.